# Take single value in a total column instead of summing the repeated value

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Objective:**

I need to SUM the total amount per country. In the example below. the total should be 200. But obviously, I'm getting 600. Basically, I need the value in the total column for each customer id and have it broken down by country

**Situation:**

My model has the following dimensions

```
+--------------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------------+
| country name | customer id | order id | Price_total | price before tax |
+--------------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------------+
| france       |         123 |       11 |   200       |    59.99         |
| france       |         123 |       11 |   200       |    35.99         |
| france       |         123 |       12 |   200       |   109.99         |
+--------------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------------+
```

**Output should be:**

France: 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to aggregate your table into one with no repeated values and then sum.

```
Total =
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table1,
        Table1[country name],
        Table1[customer id],
        "Price", MAX ( Table1[Price_total] )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( Summary, [Price] )
```

The summary table has a row each unique combination of `country name` and `customer id` and calculates the maximal `Price_total` for each unique combination (instead of the sum). Then you iterate through that table and add up the `Price` for each row in that summary table.